# Can we do auto adjust of column size on the basis of length of the data in GWT

Tags: gwt

Since the way in the MS excel when  we click on the grid it auto adjust to the size of the data in the grid. Can we have same functionality here also in GWt.

Answer (score 0):

You can program this by hand by getting the offsetWidth of all elements in the dataGrid or whatever you are using and keep track of the max.

Comment: Thanks dude for useful suggestion.